# How to to get the string value of custom field (single select) using listener in jira

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am a new learner of Jira and I have no experience with Script runner, And I trying to Write a script in ScriptRunner that gets initiated every time a user selects the “other” option. the "other" is one of four options which I added it under custom field and the type of this field is single select.
what i have done is open scriptrunner> create listener> choose Custom listener> select the project> and write this script:

```
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def cField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("impacted")
def cFieldValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cField)

If cFieldValue== "Other"    
  return "there is no another option"
```

this script didn't work with me. can any one give me .
Can someone give me advice or help for script?

Answer (score 1):

Simply append a .toString()

```
def cFieldValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cField).toString()
```

Maby you can replace your whole code with:

```
def cFieldValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue("impacted").toString()
```